# Running InteractiveBrokers Client Portal API Gateway in a Docker container

Tags: docker, http, https, ip, interactive-brokers

I am trying to setup the [InteractiveBrokers Client Portal API Gateway](https://ibkrcampus.com/ibkr-api-page/cpapi/) to run inside a Docker container, where I will only access it from the local host. I want the solution to be independent of OS, primarily Windows or Linux.

I am able to configure a Docker container such that the gateway runs, but when I try to access it, I get `Access Denied`. I believe this is from the actual gateway, so I am at least connecting to it.

[image: Access Denied]

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /home
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install default-jre wget unzip -y
RUN wget https://download2.interactivebrokers.com/portal/clientportal.gw.zip
RUN unzip clientportal.gw.zip -d ./clientportal.gw
WORKDIR /home/clientportal.gw
CMD ./bin/run.sh ./root/conf.yaml
```

I build and run the Docker image and container, respectively, with:

```
docker build -t clientportal ./
docker run -p 5000:5000 -it clientportal
```

I have also modified the `conf.yaml` to allow various IP ranges:

```yaml
ips:
  allow:
    - 192.*
    - 131.216.*
    - 127.0.0.1
    - host.docker.internal
    - 172.17.0.*
  deny:
    - 212.90.324.10
```

It's my understanding that `host.docker.internal` is the hostname of the host from the perspective of the Docker container, and that Docker container's `localhost`'s resolve to `172.17.0.*`. These are the two additional ranges I added to the default list. It is also my understanding this IP is a whitelist of IP addresses that can connect *to* the gateway. I'm not sure what IP address range I am missing for the host when trying to connect to the gateway running inside the Docker container. If I run the gateway directly in Windows, then I can connect and authenticate.

What IP should I waitlist in `conf.yaml` to make this work? What other settings do I need? Besides the above, I have also inspected the [`conf.yaml`](https://github.com/Voyz/ibeam/blob/master/copy_cache/clientportal.gw/root/conf.yaml) in the [IBeam repository](https://github.com/Voyz/ibeam) and don't see any major differences. I have also tried the IP ranges there to no avail.